# Demora em retorno subscribe - Angular4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Iniciei os estudos com angular4.
Fiz uma requisição simples que me retorna um `json`.
Até ai tudo bem...
Ao fazer a comparação em meu `component` com o dados retornados do meu `service`, o mesmo me apresenta um erro no console:

---

Script to `component` aonde gera erro:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

//importando o serviço
import { CredentialsService } from './services/credentials.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public cred: CredentialsService) {}

  verifyUser(user, pw){
    let dados;
    this.cred.getCredentials().subscribe(res =>{
      dados = res;
    });
    //o if fora do subscribe gera erro...
    if(user == dados.credentials.user && pw == dados.credentials.password){
      console.log('usuário logado');
    }else{
      console.log('usuário e senha errados');
    }
  }


  ngOnInit() {

  }

}
```

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'credentials' of undefined

---

Porém quando eu coloco a comparação(if) dentro do `subscribe`, o código funciona...
Pq ocorre este problema?

Código "funcional":

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

//importando o serviço
import { CredentialsService } from './services/credentials.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public cred: CredentialsService) {}

  verifyUser(user, pw){
    let dados;
    this.cred.getCredentials().subscribe(res =>{
      dados = res;
      if(user == dados.credentials.user && pw == dados.credentials.password){
        console.log('usuário logado');
      }else{
        console.log('usuário e senha errados');
      }
    });
  }


  ngOnInit() {

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Porquê quando você colocou o if fora da função subscribe, ele foi executado antes do retorno da sua promise. E portanto, a propriedade **credentials** do seu **response** era **undefined**:

> *ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'credentials' of undefined.*

Já quando você colocou dentro da função subscribe, o if só foi executado quando a promise retornou, e nesse caso havia valor em `dados.credentials.user`.